# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm trying to load some static pages and files (images, css and javascripts) in my rails application for testing. But no image is loaded nor bootstrap rendering. I have attempted different options as looked up on Stackoverflow as below before running on it on the server (with `rails server`)

- use the command `rake assets:precompile` and use 'rake tmp:clear' or manually delete stuff inside the tmp directory
- change the HTML syntax of the image tag to open different images under the resource directory `../../assets/images/hero-images/*.jpg` like:

Before:
`<img src="../../assets/images/hero-images/abyssal_underlord_sb.png">`

Now: 
`<%= image_tag("../../assets/images/hero-images/abyssal_underlord_sb.png") %>`

The `../..` basically tells me that I have to go back to the `app` directory to access the images folder, but it still doesn't work

- As there's a reason with the production environment settings that I should run it on the setting,  tried `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but no luck as well.

**Update**:

- Lastly, try to fix the configuration in the `config` directory. I have this line `config.serve_static_assets = true` in the `development.rb` file in the app (and even try `rake assets:precompiles` but still no luck.

Here's the snapshot of the part of my directory tree to refer for helping me troubleshoot these problems. 
[image]

Comment: Are you doing this on local development ?

Comment: @AjayBarot Yes, I'm working on my local machine, running the test with rails server

Comment: ok. You don't need to precompile the assets for rendering images on local server. Also you don't need to set serve_static_assets to true for local server.

Comment: Do this 1. set `config.serve_static_assets = false` in `development.rb`. 2. Change image_tag to this `<%= image_tag("hero-images/abyssal_underlord_sb.png") %>`. 3. Now start the server and check your image. your image should be on this location. `your_project/app/images/hero-images/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can render the images which located at inner folder of `assets/images` by 2 ways.

1 Add following in `application.rb`

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'hero-images')

Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  config.assets.paths << path
end
```

Access the image directly

```
<img src="assets/hero-images/abyssal_underlord_sb.png">
<%= image_tag("abyssal_underlord_sb.png")%>
```

2.  Simply add inner folder name above the file name.

```
<%= image_tag("hero-images/abyssal_underlord_sb.png")%>
```

Refer to this link https://learn.co/lessons/images-and-the-asset-pipeline

Comment: Please note the folder after the assets "hero-images/abyssal_underlord_sb.png"

Comment: Well I have used this code in my own project and this works fine

Comment: Thanks @AjayBarot! I tried the 2nd way, and it works.

Comment: @AjayBarot: What will be the solution for a case where the images work fine on local but gives "404 not found" error on production?